# C++ difference in sending an array as a value/pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, arguments

So I somehow got this to work, I am really interested as to why my first attempt failed.

I have informal experience with C, and am now trying to learn C++. I thought I would experiment with a few common commands, such as passing arguments to a function, but recieved an "incomplete type error" when trying to acess the contents of a passed array.

This is the erroneous code:

```
    void printoutarray(int array[][], int height, int width){
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
                cout << array[x][y]) << " ";
            }
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
```

I was able to fix the code using pointers:

```
    void printoutarray(int *array, int height, int width){
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
                cout << *(array+x*width+y) << " ";
            }
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
```

and by passing the array like this:

```
    #define hght 5
    #define wdth 5
    /*Other code/main function*/
    int inputarray[hght][wdth] = {{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15},{16,17,18,19,20},{21,22,23,24,25}};
    printoutarray(*inputarray, hght, wdth);
```

But my question is why to I have to specifically send the function a pointer of the array. Shouldn't the array variable be a pointer itself? Also, why did I need to include the dereference operator in my "fixed" code, is it because I am sending a pointer of a pointer? Again I'm mostly curious about the workings of the language, so any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There's nothing here that would be any different in C.

Comment: The `int[][]` isn't right. You *must* supply the length for the second dimension.

Comment: You're right, but why? Is it to prevent buffer overflow?

Comment: No, it's because to correctly calculate the offset from a pointer the compiler has to know the size of the object being pointed to. So it has to know the size of the second dimension. Or in the case of a 3D array it would need to know the size of the second and third dimensions. Only the first dimension can be left out, otherwise the compiler cannot know the size of the objects being pointed to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are converted to pointers when passed to a function (true in C and C++). Your mistake seems to be thinking that because of this a 2D array should be converted to a double pointer when passed to a function, that isn't true.

You have a 2D array

```
int inputarray[hght][wdth] = ...;
```

One way of looking at this is that it's an array of size `hght`, each element of this array is another array of size `wdth`. So when converting this array to a pointer, you get a pointer to an array of size `wdth`. Like this

```
void printoutarray(int array[][wdth], int height, int width){
```

or more explicitly like this

```
void printoutarray(int (*array)[wdth], int height, int width){
```

With either of these slight changes your original code will work. Though in both cases the `width` parameter is useless, because this function only works on arrays with width `wdth`

Nothing happening here that wouldn't also work exactly the same way in C.

Comment: That makes sense, and explains why I needed the width in my "fixed" code. Thanks!

Comment: @user1639852 Exactly, that's well put, I should have said that myself.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactial/typos aside, there is no essential difference between those two functions. The "pass by value" doesn't pass by value at all, just like C, it passes a pointer to the first element. I would be very surprised if the compiler output for the two functions you have given are different in any meaningful way.

Comment: One failed to compile, while the second ran successfully. I was surprised about the difference as well, but John's response makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "syntactical/typos aside" - obviously, you will need to have correct code. But if you add the size to the second [] in the argument, it will not be any difference in, say, performance or the size of the code - because essentially it does the same thing in both cases. [It is of course easier to read `array[y][x]` than `array + (y * width + x)`]